# App building issue, running from past 45 minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am working on an android app. When I try to build, It starts and not finishing even after 45 minutes. I tried restarting, invalidate & restart. Still no luck. See the below image REF[image]

Comment: how much RAM your pc have ?

Comment: its depend on your dependency size. Example: if you are using mopub like library it will take around 30-40 minute for building released build(16GB Ram)